# How to close/cancel a Clientdataset before retrieving all records

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi 7 and ClientDataset-Provider-AdoQuery framework, is there anyway to cancel a query before retrieving all records. I want the user to have the option of cancelling the query if it takes too much time and change the parameters and try again....

Comment: It looks like this question has been asked before (maybe not here) if I google "delphi (interrupt or cancel) query". Maybe that helps

Comment: I spent some hours searching it. It is asked many times but I could not find a working answer... I just want to know if there is any method or something that I can call to cancel the query...

Comment: Maybe fire your queries off in separate threads? Then a user abort would be ignoring the thread result. Your queries must be able to run concurrently (shouldn't be a problem with most databases), and the database performance will suffer because the abandoned query is still running while the modified one is being executed.

Comment: Alternatively, isn't there anything you can do up-front? Like warning the user about the large number of items he has selected ("Query may take long"), or firing off a simpler query first that will tell the user that he is gonna get 100000 results whih will take a long time?

Comment: @Jan: You are right but I think this can be a powerful option fr users workng with large databases.I found something on ADOQuery component. There is an Event called OnFetchProgress. It seems that this event is called while query is running every n miliseconds and there are some controlling mechanisms here. I have just started working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should decide first what is "too long" for you. Suppose it 120 sec for example. Set TADOQuery.CommandTimeout (or what you use) to 120. Now if execution of the command (probably select in your case) will take more than 120 sec, then you get specific exception and you can do what you want (show message to user, change parameters of the query, ...).
If connection to server may take long time, you can do same for TADOConnection.ConnectionTimeout property.